# Facebook was discussing about this patent in other blog, how can we find out what they are looking for?

Tags: patentability

In reference to the patent: [US20150033147](https://www.google.com/patents/US20150033147)

I see in other blog that Facebook and twitter inquired about this patent, how can we find out that how big company search for which / type of patent?

Comment: Could you add a link to the blog post you are referring to?

Answer (score 1):

For reference, this application was abandoned on 09/18/2017:
https://register.epo.org/ipfwretrieve?apn=US.201313953728.A&lng=en

Comment: Although this answers the question, it isn't very helpful in the general sense. Much better would be for you to describe how you reached this conclusion with links to the site the information was found on.

Comment: I’m happy to upvote your answer.